# Multipanel barcharts using facetgrid in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-grid

I have a data as follows. I want to create a multipanel chart, where the two vertical panels are site  and  the horizontal panel (on left), are Time, and Y ticks for each time are Name, and the count are the horizontal bar chart on X axis and finally the colour of each bars are the Active period. I tried lots of ways to write but each time I get more error. I also want to show the counts on bars.

```
Name | Active_period| site |Time | count
A | Last_year| north| mornings |10
A | Last_year| south| mornings |20
A | Last_year| north| evenings|45
A | Last_year| south| evenings|35
A | this_year| north| mornings |80
A | this_year| south| mornings |60
A | this_year| north| evenings|95
A | this_year| south| evenings|120
A | study_year| north| mornings |100
A | study_year| south| mornings |400
A | study_year| north| evenings|220
A | study_year| south| evenings|32
B | Last_year| north| mornings |10
B | Last_year| south| mornings |45
B | Last_year| north| evenings|25
B | Last_year| south| evenings|20
B | this_year| north| mornings |300
B | this_year| south| mornings |250
B | this_year| north| evenings|140
B | this_year| south| evenings|20
B | study_year| north| mornings |10
B | study_year| south| mornings |20
B | study_year| north| evenings|10
B | study_year| south| evenings|20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `facet_grid` and a `geom_col`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(count, Name, fill = Active_period)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(Time ~ site)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- structure(list(Name = c(
  "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ",
  "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "A ", "B ", "B ", "B ", "B ", "B ", "B ",
  "B ", "B ", "B ", "B ", "B ", "B "
), Active_period = c(
  " Last_year",
  " Last_year", " Last_year", " Last_year", " this_year", " this_year",
  " this_year", " this_year", " study_year", " study_year", " study_year",
  " study_year", " Last_year", " Last_year", " Last_year", " Last_year",
  " this_year", " this_year", " this_year", " this_year", " study_year",
  " study_year", " study_year", " study_year"
), site = c(
  " north",
  " south", " north", " south", " north", " south", " north", " south",
  " north", " south", " north", " south", " north", " south", " north",
  " south", " north", " south", " north", " south", " north", " south",
  " north", " south"
), Time = c(
  " mornings ", " mornings ", " evenings",
  " evenings", " mornings ", " mornings ", " evenings", " evenings",
  " mornings ", " mornings ", " evenings", " evenings", " mornings ",
  " mornings ", " evenings", " evenings", " mornings ", " mornings ",
  " evenings", " evenings", " mornings ", " mornings ", " evenings",
  " evenings"
), count = c(
  10L, 20L, 45L, 35L, 80L, 60L, 95L, 120L,
  100L, 400L, 220L, 32L, 10L, 45L, 25L, 20L, 300L, 250L, 140L,
  20L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 20L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -24L
))
```